# Cannot gzip slices with more than 32768 bytes in Go 1.5 on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, go, gzip

I am trying to compress byte slices in Go using `compress/gzip`. Whenever I  compress slices with lengths longer than 2^15 on my laptop, every byte with an index of 2^15 or greater is set to 0 after decompression. When I run the same code on my research cluster it also breaks.

Calling `go version` on my laptop prints:

```
$ go version
go version go1.5 darwin/amd64
```

Calling `go version` on the cluster prints:

```
$ go version
go version go1.3.3 linux/amd64
```

Below is a demonstrative test file that I wrote. It generates random slices of different lengths, compresses them, then decompresses them. It checks that no calls returns errors and also checks that the compressed and decompressed slices are the same:

```
package compress

import (
    "bytes"
    "compress/gzip"
    "math/rand"
    "testing"
)

func byteSliceEq(xs, ys []byte) bool {
    if len(xs) != len(ys) { return false }
    for i := range xs {
        if xs[i] != ys[i] { return false }
    }
    return true
}

func TestGzip(t *testing.T) {
    tests := []struct {
        n int
    }{
        { 1<<10 },
        { 1<<15 },
        { 1<<15 + 1 },
        { 1<<20 },

    }

    rand.Seed(0)

    for i := range tests {
        n := tests[i].n

        in, out := make([]byte, n), make([]byte, n)
        buf := &bytes.Buffer{}
        for i := range in { in[i] = byte(rand.Intn(256)) }

        writer := gzip.NewWriter(buf)
        _, err := writer.Write(in)
        if err != nil {
            t.Errorf("%d) n = %d: writer.Write() error: %s",
                i + 1, n, err.Error())
        }
        err = writer.Close()
        if err != nil {
            t.Errorf("%d) n = %d: writer.Close() error: %s",
                i + 1, n, err.Error())
        }

        reader, err := gzip.NewReader(buf)
        if err != nil {
            t.Errorf("%d) n = %d: gzip.NewReader error: %s",
                i + 1, n, err.Error())
        }
        reader.Read(out)
        err = reader.Close()
        if err != nil {
            t.Errorf("%d) n = %d: reader.Close() error: %s",
                i + 1, n, err.Error())
        }

        if !byteSliceEq(in, out) {
            idx := -1
            for i := range in {
                if in[i] != out[i] {
                    idx = i
                    break
                }
            }
            t.Errorf("%d) n = %d: in[%d] = %d, but out[%d] = %d",
                i + 1, n, idx, in[idx], idx, out[idx])
        }
    }
}
```

When I run this test, I get the following output:

```
$ go test --run "TestGzip"
--- FAIL: TestGzip (0.12s)
    gzip_test.go:77: 3) n = 32769: in[32768] = 78, but out[32768] = 0
    gzip_test.go:77: 4) n = 1048576: in[32768] = 229, but out[32768] = 0
FAIL
exit status 1
```

Does anyone know what is going on here? Am I misusing the package in some way? Let me know if I haven't given enough information.

Comment: <strike>Can you try go 1.6?</strike>

Comment: Not yet. There are no references to bug fixes in the release history, but I can try and see what happens. Also, in the original version of the question, I said that it worked on my cluster, but upon retesting, I found that I was in the wrong directory when I ran the test and that I get the same results on the cluster.

Comment: I just tested, it doesn't work on go1.4 -> tip, it might be a bug, worth filing an issue on the bug tracker.

Comment: You're not reading until EOF. BTW, there's [`bytes.Equal`](https://golang.org/pkg/bytes/#Equal)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is in this line:

```
reader.Read(out)
```

There is no guarantee that [`Reader.Read()`](https://golang.org/pkg/compress/gzip/#Reader.Read) will read the whole `out` slice *in one step*.

[`gzip.Reader.Read()`](https://golang.org/pkg/compress/gzip/#Reader.Read) is to implement [`io.Reader.Read()`](https://golang.org/pkg/io/#Reader).
Quoting from its doc (the *"general contract"*):

> ```
> Read(p []byte) (n int, err error)
> ```
>
> Read reads **up to** len(p) bytes into p.

There is no guarantee that `Reader.Read()` will read until `out` is filled, it may stop at fewer bytes if the implementation wishes so (even if EOF is not reached). If you pass a "big" slice, this may easily happen if an internal cache of the implementation is exhausted. `Read()` returns the number of read bytes (and an `error`), you may use that to check if the full slice was read.

Or even better, instead you may use [`io.ReadFull()`](https://golang.org/pkg/io/#ReadFull) to make sure `out` is read fully:

```
if _, err = io.ReadFull(reader, out); err != nil {
    t.Errorf("Error reading full out slice:", err)
}
```

By applying this change, your test passes.

Comment: Yes, this fixed it completely. Silly me, forgetting my fundamentals. Thank you!